# user post count for a specific table

Tags: post, count

I am attempting to count the user posts for a specific table. I have referenced the following codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts
but I keep outputting a value of zero for my user count. My function is

```
function count_user_posts_ship_to_you( $userid, $post_type = 'post', $public_only = false ) {
global $wpdb;
$NumPosts = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ship_to_us` WHERE `user_id` = $userid" );
return $NumPosts; }
```

The process part that inputs into my table is referenced below:

```
$x_fields = 'ip, NumPosts';
$x_values = f_getIP() . "', '" . count_user_posts_ship_to_you($_POST['user_id']);

/*Check to see if the table exists and if it doesn't create it.*/
if ( !f_tableExists($table, DB_NAME) ) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID),
        ip int NOT NULL,
        NumPosts int NOT NULL
    )";
/*Insert out values into the database.*/
$sql="INSERT INTO $table ($x_fields) VALUES ('$x_values')";
```

I have also tried other solutions from other similar posts of this question but have not helped me resolve the problem. Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried running the raw query directly against your MySQL database?  Have you verified that you actually have data for that user?

Comment: @Tim Yes I have tried using the raw sql query against the MySQL database, but can you write out how you would do that so I can double check if I did it correctly? Yes I have verified I do have data for the user and when I run the count query directly in mySQL, I am getting the correct count. For some reason the query is not outputting the value properly to store it